# Converting Unix Timestamp to Time Ago Format in twig

Tags: datetime

I'm working on a project where I need to convert a Unix timestamp to a "time ago" format (e.g., "2 hours ago," "3 days ago," etc.) using Twig. I've tried using the `{{ created|date('M Y, D') }}` function, but it only provides a regular date and time format.

Can someone please guide me on how to modify the code to achieve the desired "time ago" format? I want to display the elapsed time since the timestamp in a more human-readable format.

If there are any specific functions, libraries, or code examples available in Twig that can help with this conversion, I would greatly appreciate the guidance.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: In Twig, you can utilize the date filter for formatting date objects. However, it doesn't directly provide a "time ago" format. This functionality is typically achieved through a custom Twig filter or extension.